# navigate to a react native page from webview

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, android-webview, postmessage

I have a react native app that uses webView to render an html code , i used postmessage for communicating between them. webview will send message to react native to open another react native page ( for example send message 'open login page' ) so i will recieve it in onMessage (event) , then when i want to use `this.props.navigateTo` it says 'can not read property navigateTo of undefined' . 
i used `console.log(this)` and understood 'this' is **DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope**, that i can't use `navigatTo()` . how can i use navigatTo in this case (while im in DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope) or how can i close or stop rendering webview to do this?

```
  onMessage( event ) {
    let post = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
    console.log(event)
   switch(post.message){

       case 'open login page':
           console.log(this); // 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope'
          this.props.navigateTo('login'); //'can not read property navigation of undefined'
           break;
   }
}
```

this is the webview :

```
  <WebView
            // onNavigationStateChange={async (e) => {
            //     console.log(e);
            //      if (async() => await getKey('isLogged') === false)
            //          this.props.navigateTo('login') //its ok here
            // }}
            source={{uri: isAndroid ?'file:///android_asset/html/index.html'
                :'./html/index.html'}}
            ref={ webView => this.webView = webView }
            onMessage={this.onMessage}
        />
```

i use `this.props.navigatTo()` for navigating and its ok but in this case state doesnt change to run this here ,
  and this is my stacknavigator :

```
  login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    app: {
        screen: App  // webview defined here
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem myself :)) I should use bind,
OnMessage = { this.onMessage.bind (this) }
I just forgot it ...